# Custom Control Dependency Property Binding to Property

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, custom-controls, dependency-properties

Just playing around with different types of bindings and having a property binding a Dependency Property of my custom control to another property.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BrickBreaker.Brick"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="50"  >
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="20" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding BrickFill, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Brick : UserControl
{
    public Brick()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public Brush BrickFill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrickFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BrickFillProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BrickFill.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrickFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BrickFill", typeof(Brush), typeof(Brick), null);



}
```

Implemenation In MainWindow.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BrickBreaker.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:BrickBreaker="clr-namespace:BrickBreaker" mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <BrickBreaker:Brick Margin="100,100,0,0" BrickFill="Azure"/>
</Grid>
```

Basically I want to bind the Rectangles Fill Property to the Dependency Property in the code behind.

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the exact problem? Set DataContext of UserControl to code-behind, such as:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing this: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"